# Android - Emulator layout doesnt match with telephone

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout problem.
There are 9 buttons on my layout from top to bottom.

When i run my android app on my 3.7 inc telephone, buttons seems good. But when i run on 3 inc telephone, last 2 buttons dont seem on display.

How can i fix my problem ?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/arkaplan3"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".AnaEkran" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:text="Buton"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Comment: You could start by posting your layout.  We can't guess!

Comment: Are you using a `ScrollView`?

Comment: i dont want to use scrollview.

Comment: you said there are 9 buttons, i see only one. how do have your buttons arranged?

Comment: other buttons are same. i showed example button. differens is just x,y coordinates.

Comment: Adjust the height programmatically to, at most, 1/9th the screen size.  Or don't hardcode the height.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 9 `Buttons` like you said you can:
- Resize all the `Buttons` so take them small
- Create other `layout.xml` like that you have for the different screen sizes.
Like this:

```
res/layout/your_file.xml
------------------------
res/layout-small/your_file.xml
------------------------
res/layout_big/your_file.xml
```

Also take a look a this http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html.
Hope I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put up a graphic of what your trying to do or at least all your layout file.

If were trying to achieve a basic calculator layout simply nest LinearLayout's (DO NOT NEST MORE THAN ONCE, google expectedly said not to). Then just give all your buttons the same wighting attribute to make sure they are all the same size no matter the scene

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

       <!--   </LinearLayout> -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="5.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
        android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/B1"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/B2"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/B3"
        />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/BPlus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="+" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

    </LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="5.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
        android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/B4"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/B5"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/B6"
        />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/BPlus2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="+" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```